# response.sendRedirect() in Servlet not working correctly after file upload

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets, file-upload

I have a web application with a simple upload function. The idea is to allow user select a file and upon successfully upload, redirect to `index.jsp`.

However, although the file got uploaded, the `response.redirect` is not working. After a successfully upload, the page doesn't get redirected. It just stays there. The weird thing is that I can see it is processing the `index.jsp` from the tomcat server log even though it doesn;t get redirected.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);
    boolean status=false;
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Request is not multipart, please 'multipart/form-data' enctype for your form.");
    }

    ServletFileUpload uploadHandler = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    try {

        List<FileItem> items = uploadHandler.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/upload"), item.getName());
                item.write(file);
                writer.write("{\"name\":\"" + item.getName() + "\",\"type\":\"" + item.getContentType() + "\",\"size\":\"" + item.getSize() + "\"}");

            }

        }

        //redirect to index.jsp if successfully

        redirect(request, response);

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
      writer.close();
    }

}
```

The redirect method:

```
private void redirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

The file upload plugin is from `https://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload`
I used the front-end and developed the upload event handler using java apache fileupload. Everything works fine except the redirect part.

The application.js file which handles the JSON returns:

```
$(function () {
// Initialize jQuery File Upload (Extended User Interface Version):
$('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX();

// Load existing files:
$.getJSON($('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX('option', 'url'), function (files) {
    var options = $('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX('option');
    options.adjustMaxNumberOfFiles(-files.length);
    $.each(files, function (index, file) {
        options.buildDownloadRow(file, options)
            .appendTo(options.downloadTable).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

});

Any ideas?

Comment: The code looks fine. However, if you uncomment one of the two outcomments right before the `try`, then the redirect will indeed potentially fail (with an `IllegalStateException` in the server logs). Are you really running the code you think you're running?

Comment: I have managed to trace down the problem. Yes, you are right, the upload handler works fine. The problem is with the front-end js script that is running. After each successful upload, there is a need to return a JSON response, which causes whatever code that are attached thereafter to fail. I have edited the codes above to show the problem. Are there any fix to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to send two responses on a single request. One with JSON data in the response body and one which redirects the response to another request. This is not going to work. You can send **only one** response back per request. A redirect requires an untouched (uncommitted) response body, otherwise the redirect will just fail with `IllegalStateException: response already committed` in the server logs.

You need to move the redirect call from the servlet code to JavaScript code. Get rid of the `redirect()` line in the servlet and add the following line as the last line of the `$.getJSON()` callback function.

```
window.location = '/index.jsp';
```

This way JavaScript will take care of the redirect.